# Safe Navigation Operator works a little bit strange

Tags: apex

The code:

```
Contact cnt1 = new Contact(LastName = 'test');
Contact cnt2;

System.debug(cnt1.LastName);                   // <-- as expected: 'test'
System.debug(cnt2?.LastName);                  // <-- as expected: null

System.debug(cnt1.LastName != cnt2?.LastName); // <-- as NOT expected: false
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm

Is anybody able to explain this behavior?

Added later:

and same behavior for user defined classes (not only for SObject):

```
class Test {
    Test(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    public String field;
}

Test t1 = new Test('test');
Test t2;

System.debug(t1.field);               // <-- as expected: 'test'
System.debug(t2?.field);              // <-- as expected: null

System.debug(t1.field != t2?.field);  // <-- as NOT expected: false
System.debug(t1.field == t2?.field);  // <-- as NOT expected: true
System.debug(t2?.field != t1.field);  // <-- as expected: true

System.debug(String.valueOf(cnt1.field) != String.valueOf(cnt2?.field)); // also false
System.debug('' + cnt1.field != '' + cnt2?.field);                       // as expected - true
```

interesting that when we use operator '==' we have result true... What system try to compare in this lines?

In addition, System.assertEquals and System.assertNotEquals have compilation errors when trying to use this operator.

```
class B {
    string field = 'Test';
}
B b1 = new B(), b2;
//System.TypeException: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, Boolean
System.assertEquals(true, b1.field != b2?.field);
```

Comment: Interestingly, it works as expected if you swap the order `cnt2?.LastName != cnt1.LastName`.

Comment: This is a brand new operator, so there's bound to be a few glitches. I'll let someone know. You should submit a case with support.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves: Also works irrespective of ordering, when we store the LastName properties to a string variables and use string variable for comparison. Looks like a bug, [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) doesn't have this behavior.

Comment: @krisGonsales, yes, but why it not works in opposite order? i try to understand how comparison can be evaluated to have result equal to false and unable to imagine this - only have idea that comparison not executed at all and for some reason returned false. but why?

Comment: @sfdcfox - unfortunately i unable to reach the 'development' support, have no such support plan.

Comment: (In addition to the snippets listed in this post,) I've seen some more weird behavior with this operator and I'm sure others would have noticed the same. As others have pointed out, this would most definitely be a salesforce bug. I believe that safe navigation operator is not really meant to be used with comparison operator at this time. [Apex Dev Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) indicates to avoid using this with assignment operator, but may have missed mentioning about comparison operator.

Comment: Also, none of the code samples provided in the release notes as well as dev guide show the usage of comparison operator with this safe navigation operator.

Comment: @arut - for assignment this have sense - we unable to assign to null. And by the doc this will cause the compiling time error. For comparison we just need to evaluate two expressions and compare the results.

Comment: True. Considering the comparison scenarios where this operator doesn't work as expected, the common rationale (_simple evaluation & comparison, operator precedence, right/left associative operation etc._) doesn't seem to be applicable. Its just my guess that this operator was not meant to be used for comparison at the moment [_I feel that SF apex team should have definitely spotted something as simple as this operation_]. Not denying that I could be wrong.

Comment: I added one additional bug example (CompileFail: types must be compatible, string, boolean) I found while logging this case. Engineering is on it.

Answer (score 12):

Somehow it works only in the first place of comparison operator (or when storing values to variables):

```
System.debug(cnt2?.LastName != cnt1.LastName);
```

Parentheses also does not help. Out of curiosity I have tried to compare both sides with safe navigation operators:

```
Contact cnt2;
Contact cnt3;
System.debug(cnt2?.LastName != cnt3?.LastName);
```

But this throws `FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error` in Developer Console.

I think, that replacement mechanism does not work properly at this time and it is Salesforce bug.

Comment: I've brought this to Chris Peterson's attention. We should have a more official answer today sometime.

Comment: @sfdcfox Seems that nobody will comment this from the SF side.

Comment: I have logged a case as a Premier+ Support customer, we should have feedback shortly. I appreciate you following up with me.

Comment: @sfdcfox Was there any update on your case with the Premier+ support? Just curious to know about any new information for this problem.

Comment: @arut See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Edit

All of the issues in this question now appear to be resolved. Some tests that were previously reporting inverted results (e.g. comparisons that returned true instead of false) are now fixed, comparison types are now fixed, user classes no longer exhibit weird behaviors, the compilation errors and Internal Server Errors all appear to be fixed, etc. I will continue to experiment with this operator, as I have a lot of things I plan on patching with this operator, but it now seems to be fixed.

---

I have been in contact with Premier Support, R&D has confirmed the bug, and a patch is planned for December 3rd, 2020, 5:00PM PST. This should resolve the errors with this operator. I will follow up with this over the weekend of December 5th, 2020 to confirm that the behavior is indeed fixed, and take any further action if necessary.

Comment: thanks for your efforts!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the update.

Comment: @sfdcfox - was this indeed fixed?

Comment: @AlejandroFlores Thanks for reminding me. I've edited this answer. It does appear that all of the various errors, compilation errors, runtime errors, and inverted comparison results are all fixed. I'll update this answer if I find any remaining bugs, but it seems to be solid now.